Cleveref doesn't outputs only the first letter capitalised
So I'm using cleveref and want to capitalise the first letter of the references. However, if I use either \Cref or \usepacekage[capitalise]{cleveref} then the whole word is capitalised. Here is my sty file
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
% \newdir{ >}{*!/-5pt/@{>}}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   sorting=nyt, 
   citestyle=numeric,
   bibstyle=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ressources/biblio.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, %colorise les liens
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
pdftitle={}, pdfauthor={}, pdfsubject={}
}

\newcommand{\ssi}{if and only if }
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e. }

\DeclareMathOperator{\KK}{\mathds{K}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\FF}{\mb{F}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CC}{\mb{C}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RR}{\mb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\QQ}{\mb{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ZZ}{\mb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NN}{\mb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\NNp}{\mb{N}\setminus\{0\}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LL}{\mb{L}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rk}


\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\ms}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\somme}[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\sommedir}[2]{\bigoplus\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\produit}[2]{\prod\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\fa}{\forall\,}
\newcommand{\exi}{\exists\,}
\newcommand{\exii}{\exists!\,}
\newcommand{\tq}{\,|\,}
\newcommand{\intn}[2][0]{\llbracket#1;#2\rrbracket}
\newcommand{\nn}{\intn{n}}
\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}
\newcommand{\kx}[1][X]{\KK[#1]}
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\com}[1]{\lie{#1}{#1}}

\newcommand{\inter}[2]{\bigcap\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\union}[2]{\bigcup\limits_{#1}^{#2}}

\newcommand{\mfg}{\mf{g}}
\newcommand{\mfh}{\mf{h}}
\newcommand{\mff}{\mf{f}}
\newcommand{\mfr}{\mf{r}}
\newcommand{\gmod}[1][\mfg]{$#1$-module}
\newcommand{\gmods}[1][\mfg]{$#1$-modules}
\newcommand{\gmor}[1][\mfg]{$#1$-homomorphism}
\newcommand{\gmors}[1][\mfg]{$#1$-homomorphisms}
\newcommand{\rmod}[1][R]{$#1$-module}
\newcommand{\rmods}[1][R]{$#1$-modules}
\newcommand{\ab}{^{ab}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\M}{\ms{M}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{\ms{GL}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{\mc{I}d}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vect}{Vect}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\isom}{\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homm}{Hom}
\newcommand{\Hom}[2][\cc]{\Homm_{#1}(#2)}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Torr}{Tor}
\newcommand{\Tor}[4]{\Torr^{#1}_{#2}(#3,#4)}
\newcommand{\tensor}[1]{\otimes_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Sn}[1][n]{\mf{S}_{#1}}

%    Norm notation
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\newcommand{\normt}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}

% Categories

\DeclareMathOperator{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mod}{\mathbf{Mod}}
\newcommand{\Modd}[1][R]{{_{#1}\Mod}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mmodd}{\mathbf{mod}}
\newcommand{\modd}[1][\mfg]{{_{#1}\mmodd}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lie}{\mathbf{Lie}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alg}{\mathbf{Alg}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{\mathbf{Vect}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\fvect}{\mathbf{FVect}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{\mathbf{Spec}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CH}{\mathbf{CH}}
\newcommand{\CHg}{\CH_{\geq0}}
\newcommand{\CHgg}{\CH^{\geq0}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Grp}{\mathbf{Grp}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ab}{\mathbf{Ab}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\objj}{obj}
\newcommand{\obj}[1][\cc]{\objj(#1)}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cone}{cone}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fr}{Fr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tott}{Tot}
\newcommand{\Tot}[1][C]{\Tott(#1)}
\newcommand{\Totp}[1][C]{\Tott^{\Pi}(#1)}
\newcommand{\Tots}[1][C]{\Tott^{\oplus}(#1)}

\newcommand{\cc}{\mc{C}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mc{D}}
\newcommand{\map}[1]{\overset{#1}{\to}}
\newcommand{\epi}{\twoheadrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ses}[3]{#1\rightarrowtail #2\epi #3}
\renewcommand{\sec}{\ses{A}{B}{C}}
\newcommand{\sesmap}[5]{#1\overset{#2}{\rightarrowtail} #3 \overset{#4}{\epi} #5}

% Lie aglebras

\newcommand{\lie}[2]{[#1,\!#2]}
\DeclareMathOperator{\genl}{Lie}
\newcommand{\ug}[1][\mfg]{\mathscr{U}(#1)}
\newcommand{\ig}[1][\mfg]{\mathscr{I}(#1)}

% Theorem styles

\newtheorem{theo}{{\textsf{Theorem}}}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theo]{{\textsf{Lemma}}}
\newtheorem{cor}[theo]{{\textsf{Corollary}}}
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{{\textsf{Proposition}}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{rk}{{\textsf{Remark}}}[section]
\newtheorem{rks}[rk]{{\textsf{Remarks}}}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{{\textsf{Definition}}}
\newtheorem{defis}[theo]{{\textsf{Definitions}}}
\newtheorem*{nota}{{\textsf{Notation}}}
\newtheorem*{notas}{{\textsf{Notations}}}
\newtheorem{ex}{{\textsf{Example}}}[section]
\newtheorem{exs}[ex]{{\textsf{Examples}}}
\newtheorem{ctrex}[ex]{{\textsf{Counter-example}}}
\newtheorem{rem}{\textsf{Reminder}}
\theoremstyle{plain} % just in case the style had changed
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{genericthm}[theo]{\thistheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedtheo}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \begin{genericthm}
   \def\@currentlabelname{the {#1}}}
  {\end{genericthm}}

% diagrams
\newcommand{\proj}[6]{
$$\xymatrix{
& #1 \ar[ld]_{#2} \ar[d]^{#3} \\
#4 \ar[r]^{#5} & #6 \ar[r] & 0.
}$$
}
\newcommand{\projp}[6]{
$$\xymatrix{
& #1 \ar[ld]_{#2} \ar[d]^{#3} \\
#4 \ar[r]^{#5} & #6 \ar[r] & 0
}$$
}

Anyone got an idea please?

Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228. Load cleveref last. Do not use $$... $$ in LaTeX.

For future reference, please do a better job building a minimal example showing your issue. Most of the preamble you included are unnecessary, and you should include also the \begin{document}...\end{document} parts so we don't have to fill it in ourselves.
A sufficient minimum example would be
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newtheorem{theo}{{\textsf{Theorem}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}\label{thm1}
        A theorem
\end{theo}

\Cref{thm1}
\end{document}


Fundamentally the issue is because you put the Theorem name in a group when you define the new theorem, you have
\newtheorem{theo}{{\textsf{Theorem}}}

so whatever mechanism that capitalizes the first letter in \Cref treats the entire object {\textsf{Theorem}} as the first letter, and hence you see your result. This is more pronounced if you change the definition to
\newtheorem{theo}{{\textsf{Theo}r}em}

which will generate

as the output.

You really shouldn't be putting formatting commands into \newtheorem{...} declarations, as that's what theorem styles are for. To get bold-face sans-serif theorem heading, you can define a new theorem style as follows
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheoremstyle{JoliaPlain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries\sffamily} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{JoliaPlain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}\label{thm1}
        A theorem
\end{theo}

\Cref{thm1}
\end{document}


Doing things this way will help you simplify your preamble, and make it easier to change styles globally. As you can see, this way \Cref also works properly with respect to the capitalization.
However, we see that the heading generated by \Cref is no longer in sans-serif. Personally I think this looks better, but as your original code would generate reference heading that is in sans serif, perhaps that's what you want. In that case, you need to manually configure cleveref by doing something like
\Crefname{theo}{\textsf{Theorem}}{\textsf{Theorems}}

since as far as I know cleveref does not provide any way to configure globally the formatting of the names of cross reference objects. Unfortunately this will require a bit of typing on your end.
